# Não consigo colocar o plugin jQuery Vegas pra funcionar

Tags: jquery, plugin

Estou tentando experimentar um plugin `jQuery` chamado `vegas` para fazer um background fullscreen mas não está dando certo, fiz de acordo com o que está no site, importei todas as bibliotecas, a `jQuery` e os arquivos `.css` do `Vegas`. Meu códigoe está assim:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <title>Untitled</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/vegas/vegas.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">

    <script src="js/vegas/vegas.js"></script>       
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('body').vegas({
            slides: [
            { src: 'img/slide1.jpg' },
            { src: 'img/slide2.jpg' },
            { src: 'img/slide3.jpg' },
            { src: 'img/slide4.jpg' },
            { src: 'img/slide5.jpg' }
            ]
            });

        </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Código CSS do body:

```
body{

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: #292929;
    background: #000;
}
```

E o local da imagem está correto e linkado na função do plugin.

[image: Local da imagem está correto]

Comment: Importe o jQuery antes do plugin, não depois.

Comment: Ainda não apareceu. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.ready` ou `$(function() {...})`, algo como:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('body').vegas({
        slides: [
        { src: 'img/slide1.jpg' },
        { src: 'img/slide2.jpg' },
        { src: 'img/slide3.jpg' },
        { src: 'img/slide4.jpg' },
        { src: 'img/slide5.jpg' }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
```

Exemplo funcionando:

```js
$(function() {
    $('body').vegas({
        slides: [
                { src: 'http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/img/poster-ja.jpg' },
                { src: 'http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/img/poster-mr.jpg' },
                { src: 'http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/img/poster-jb.jpg' },
                { src: 'http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/img/poster-jg.jpg' },
                { src: 'http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/img/poster-eg.jpg' },
                { src: 'http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/img/poster-bw.jpg' },
                { src: 'http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/img/poster-rd.jpg' },
                { src: 'http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/img/poster-pb.jpg' },
                { src: 'http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/img/poster-rl.jpg' },
                { src: 'http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/demo/img/poster-dh.jpg' }
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jaysalvat.github.io/vegas/releases/latest/vegas.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://jaysalvat.github.io/vegas/releases/latest/vegas.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: O problema está nas imagens, mas o que será que tem de errado? Será que o problema está na resolução das imagens? O tamanho delas é: 1920x1200.

Comment: Encontrei o problema @Guilherme Nascimento, eu tentei fazer com imagens locais do computador e não funcionou, então peguei links de imagens do tamanho 1920x1200 da Internet e funcionou normal.

Será que o plugin só aceita arquivos hospedados na Internet?

Comment: Guilherme, estou usando localhost, o apache, só que eu errei na hora de especificar o local da imagem colocando o diretório local e não o do localhost como se fosse em um servidor online.

Ex.: Eu estava colocando assim: src: 'img/slide5.jpg'

Quando o correto seria: src: 'http://localhost/img/slide5.jpg'

Correto?

Comment: Sim Guilherme, usei o script especificando imagens da web na resolução de 1920x1200 e funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado, já escolhi a sua resposta como a correta.

Comment: Obrigado meu amigo, deveria existir mais pessoas como você. Sucesso pra você também.